# How do we change the color and size of dingbat unicode characters in mobile Safari? (html entities)

Tags: html, css, unicode, mobile-safari, dingbats

How can we change the CSS rules of dingbats? The following does not work in iOS Safari.

```
<span class="dingbat">&#x2716;</span>

<style>
.dingbat {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Below is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue. If you open the JSFiddle in a desktop browser, the dingbat X color will be blue and the size will be 100px. But if you open it in mobile Safari, the color will be black and the size will be small.

https://jsfiddle.net/ujs80tv1/2/

---

This question was marked as a possible duplicate of "Color of Unicode Emoji". I don't think this question is a duplicate, because I definitely *can* change the color of Unicode dingbats in most browsers (see JSFiddle for example). The only browser I am not able to change the color in is mobile Safari. You cannot change the color of emojis in any browser as far as I know.

The recommended answer in the "Color of Unicode Emoji" question says to use a new font or library. That may be a workaround, but it doesn't answer the question. If someone can prove that unicode dingbats cannot be styled in mobile Safari I would accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: span in between 2 p is not a valid HTML structure, give a try display:block for the span or use a p as well and see if it works fine .... i don not have the configuration where you have your issue,.  **Could clarify as well if this happens only with dingbat or any fonts ?**

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus I updated the JSFiddle to use display: block on the .dingbat class. I am still not seeing the CSS rules apply in mobile Safari.

The problem is only happening with dingbats. I can change normal fonts in mobile Safari just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color for Unicode Emoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413731/color-for-unicode-emoji)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A response in a similar post answers this.  It worked for me!

[HTML unicode arrow works on Safari desktop, but not Safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804637/html-unicode-arrow-works-on-safari-desktop-but-not-safari-for-ios)

```
font-family: 'Zapf Dingbats';
```

Comment: This hack doesn't make any sense but it fixed the font-color for me. Thanks! I wouldn't even consider trying it out without your tip.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of the default &#x2716 style.
You have to first set a font to it.
In the css just add `font-family: "Times New Roman"`.