# Custom radio button not visible in iOs Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, angularjs, safari

I am using below mentions css to show cutom radio buttons

```
input[type=radio]{
    display:none;
}
.radio-options label::before {
    content: "\2b24";
    color:#e2e2e2;
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding-top: 1.8px;
    line-height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-options label.active-radio::before {
    content: "\2b24";
    color: #f9b410;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1.8px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

<div class="radio-options">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <input id="some_thing" type="radio"  >
        <label ng-class="{'active-radio':true}">Something</label >
      </div>
</div>
```

In desktop browser it's working correctly and showing radio button as[image]

But in safari iOs its not displaying anything
[image]

Any suggestions what could be possible cause ?

Comment: Hey,
Have you found solution for your problem? I am having same issue right now and can't find why. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, instead i used sprites and used background image with active class to mimic radio button like feature (toggle the state set the class and change background image) ;)

Comment: This might be because of a positioning issue. Try adding a position relative to your label, then position your before pseudo-element in absolute. And don't forget to put a display to it when there's the active class.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the Unicode symbol you use as a content. It doesn't seem to appear on iOS. If you change to "Black Circle" instead it will work. (Just increase the font-size to compensate the size.)

[Unicode Black Circle symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm)

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804637/html-unicode-arrow-works-on-safari-desktop-but-not-safari-for-ios)