# Ascii code of music clef in Safari on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, utf-8, safari, ascii

I can't figure out how to display ascii code &#119070 (music clef) on my web page in safari on iphone. I left out ; at the end on purpose, so you can see what the code is.

It works in Safari on Mac and in all other browsers. All the other codes that I tried worked (for example 9833 -> ♩), expect 119070 and 119074.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See if changing the font will help, the one iOS safari is using may not support the Unicode for the music clef.

[HTML unicode arrow works on Safari desktop, but not Safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804637/html-unicode-arrow-works-on-safari-desktop-but-not-safari-for-ios)

Try using zapf dingbats as done in the answer above and see if that fixes it. If not I think you may have to resort to an embedded image for iOS safari

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I thought about image myself, but text is somehow more practical in my case. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Some of the extended codes haven't been added to iOS so I'm guessing that is what is happening when it won't display. Besides an embedded image you could try the musical score emoji