# How to display a left right arrow on a webpage on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have a webpage, a post in Wordpress to be precise, with left right arrow (U+2194). Whether I type the character as it is (copy from a character map) or use the html code, I get an icon (a grey-blue rounded corner box with bold white left right arrow) on that page both on Iphone (with Safari and Opera touch) and Android (with Google Chrome). On desktop browsers I see the expected character.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit a post in Wordpress (I don't know whether a static html page will do). Copy the character "↔" and type in text mode "&#x2194;". Save the edits and publish the post.
2. Browse to that post with a desktop browser (tested with Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera on MS Windows 10) and confirm that you see the left right arrow twice.
3. Open the same post with Safari on Iphone (probably Safari on Ipad will also have the same issue) or Google Chrome on Android. What you see is an arrow icon twice, not the characters.

Answer (score 0):

This a feature of contemporary browers, see [HTML unicode arrow works on Safari desktop, but not Safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804637/html-unicode-arrow-works-on-safari-desktop-but-not-safari-for-ios).

To summarise:

- &#x2194; allows the browser to choose

  your browser's choise: ↔
- &#x2194;&#xfe0e; recommends to the browser the text version

  your browser's choise: ↔︎
- &#x2194;&#xfe0f; recommends to the browser the emoji version

  your browser's choise: ↔️